# Clicking on tag link on a question does not list other questions with that same tag

Tags: support, tags

Navigating to:

[Assign size to image in Google Slides](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76703/assign-size-to-image-in-google-slides)

shows it has been tagged with `google-slides`. The link on that page is https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-slides

When click on that link and I get this:

[image]

Why? It should at least list that one question that is tagged as `google-slides`, no?

*Edit 2015-07-26: Something got changed on the original link above. It now is tagged as `google-presentations` and not as `google-slides`, thus invalidating some of my question here:

[image]

Comment: Side note: [tag:google-presentations] has 24 questions.

Comment: @Rubén: I added an edit to show that the original question I used as a reference had its tag changed from `google-slides` to `google-presentations`.

Comment: More tags in the same situation (
`There are no frequently asked question at the moment`): 

- [tag:google-plus-circles]
- [tag:google-fusion-tables]
- [tag:atlassian]
- [tag:diaspora]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message in your screenshot tells you why:

> You are on the Frequent tab.
>   There are no frequently asked questions at the moment.
>   Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

(A question qualifies as "frequent" when it is linked from other posts.)

The choice of a tab on the tab page is "sticky"; the system remembers the last tab you opened when you were on a tag page. If you switch the tab to another one, say, "newest", navigate away and then repeat the same steps as in your question, you'll see the "newest" tab instead.

This behavior can be somewhat confusing,  which is why that message is there. The good (?) news is that this navigation system [is soon to be replaced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration).

Comment: Well, _now_ answer is valid. But, when I originally posted this question, the question I referred to, http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76703/assign-size-to-image-in-google-slides, actually had a tag of `google-slides` and not `google-presentations`. And it was at that point in time where clicking on `google-slides` revealed no questions.

Comment: So the possible bug there was was that there was at one point in time a question tagged as `google-slides`, but clicking on the tag showed nothing when clicked upon. It should have at least showed that one question in the result set.

Comment: A question qualifies as "frequent" when it is linked from other posts. If the "frequent" tab is selected, and no questions with the tag qualifies as "frequent", guess what you will see? This is what happened.