# No completion of the name after @ in comments in Meta for Web Applications

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

There seems to be no completion popup when adding a comment to a particular answer. Steps to reproduce are:

1. Navigate to [Clicking on tag link on a question does not list other questions with that same tag](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/clicking-on-tag-link-on-a-question-does-not-list-other-questions-with-that-same/3841?noredirect=1#comment3555_3841)
2. Click on the Add Comment button
3. Type "@N" and wait a second or two and see no completion: [image]
4. Notice that there is no completion for the "Normal Human" user that had added a previous comment (see image above).

I have seen this work elsewhere in the stackexchange web sites, but try as I might I cannot even reproduce it anymore (tried it in [How do I auto-reply to text messages received through Google Voice?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67645/how-do-i-auto-reply-to-text-messages-received-through-google-voice) using "@u" on the main question comment area and it did not complete the name).

Info on browser used is in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/bgoodr/e9f44372baf34faf4333#file-2015-08-01-firefox-troubleshooting-info-meta-webapps-stackexchange-com-questions-3842-txt).

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me. What browser/OS are you using? For what it's worth, you don't need an @reply there, because you're trying to address the author of the post, and they'll always get a comment notification.

Comment: @AlE.: "because you're trying to address the author of the post, and they'll always get a comment notification" is the reason. This is a bug because if there are multiple people responding to the comments, I would expect to still have "@" complete to the author of the post to be able to address the author and not some other person who had responded in the prior comments. I'll update the main post with info on the browser and OS in a bit.

Comment: I can assure you, it's not a bug. Check on [meta.se]; there've been a number of questions about this over the years.

Comment: @AlE. Understood. I'll mark http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3846/14529 as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design.

1. **You** don't get @ autocompletion because there is no point in it: the post is mine, and nobody else participated except you and me. There is nobody else there to whom your comment could be addressed.
2. **Al E.**, on the other hand, does get @ autocompletion because it makes sense for him to distinguish whether his comment is toward you or toward me.
3. If Al E., or someone else, added their comment, after that @Normal in your comment would auto-complete, for the same reason as in item 2.